# DBeaver error downloading driver libraries on connecting oracle XE

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I'm instructed by my senior to setup a local database using oracle express 21c with dbEaver setup, both software are fresh install. upon connecting there are drivers required. but I got error like this :

[image]
index 0 out of bounds for length 0

i've tried reinstalling the oracle express.oracle RDBMS also already running in the background. I wonder how can I solve this?

Comment: Not much help, but it looks like this is related to the actual DBeaver itself. No ORA- message in sight. Make sure you can connect to XE using 'sqlplus', thereafter try Oracle SQL Developer. When all of this works, go on with DBeaver troubleshooting.